# inheritance in c++ ( C::B )

Tags: c++, inheritance

i am new to c++ and not skillful in English! 
i have searched web and read same posts on this site but  did not worked for me!
its a  wonder that inheritance  used in this part of my project seems correct to me but get these error from C::B 13.12 with GNU GCC Compiler under Windows 8.1 :

```
||=== Build: Debug in test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
D:\AirportProject\Airport\aircrew.h|8|error: expected class-name before '{' token|
D:\AirportProject\Airport\aircrew.cpp||In constructor 'Aircrew::Aircrew(const string&,     const string&, long long int, const Date&, long long int, const Date&)':|
D:\AirportProject\Airport\aircrew.cpp|5|error: class 'Aircrew' does not have any field named 'Person'|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

this is my code:

person.h:

```
#include "date.h"
using namespace std;
class Person{
public:
    Person( const string&, const string&, long long, const Date& );
    void set( const string&, const string&, long long, const Date& );

private:
    char name [31];
    char last_name [31];
    long long national_code ; //long long for storing a 10 digit number
    Date birthday;
};
```

person.cpp:

```
#include "person.h"
#include <string>
 using namespace std;

 Person::Person( const string& n, const string&ln, long long ncode, const Date& D )
 { set( n, ln, ncode, D ); }
//set data members of aircrew
 void Person::set(   const string& n, const string&ln, long long ncode, const Date& D )
 {
    birthday = D ;
    strncpy( name, n.c_str(), 30 ); //converting string to char array
    strncpy( last_name, ln.c_str(), 30 );
    national_code= ncode;
 }
```

aircrew.h:

```
#include <string>
#include "person.h"
#include "date.h"
using namespace std;
class Aircrew: public Person
{
public:
    //copy-constructor
    Aircrew( const string&, const string&, long long, const Date&,
             long long, const Date& );
    //Set member data
    void set( long long, const Date& );
private:
    //long long used to be sure about 10digit numbers and more
    long long personal_code;
    // date of employment
    Date employ_date;
};
```

aircrew.cpp:

```
#include "aircrew.h"
using namespace std;

Aircrew::Aircrew( const string& n, const string& ln, long long ncode,
                  const Date& D_b, long long pcode,const Date& D_e )
        :Person( n, ln, ncode, D_b ) //base class constructor
{set( pcode, D_e );}
void Aircrew::set(long long pcode, const Date& D_e )
{
    personal_code = pcode;
    employ_date = D_e; //assignment operator( = ) is overloaded for Date class
}
```

date.h

```
class Date
 {
 public:
    Date ( int=1, int=1, int=1900 ); //Default  constructor
    void set( int, int, int );
    int getForSearch() const ;
    void print() const ;
    //assignment operator( = ) is overloaded for Date class
    Date& operator=( const Date& D )//assignment operator(=) can NOT be defined as friend
 {
    day = D.day;
    month = D.month;
    year = D.year;
    return *this;
 }

 private:
    int day, month, year;
 };
```

date.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "date.h"
using namespace std;

//Default  constructor
Date::Date( int d, int m, int y) { set( d, m, y ); }
//set() function sets the entered date if its valid
void Date::set( int d, int m, int y )
{
    day=( d>0? d: 1);
    month=( m>0? m: 1);
    year= ( y>0? y: 1900);
}

//getForSearch () returns  an integer like yyyymmdd for easy search
int Date::getForSearch () const
{
    return ((year*100 + month)*100 + day);
}

//print Date in the form of mm/dd/yyyy
void Date::print () const
{
    cout << " " << month  << "/" << day << "/" << year;
}
```

and also an empty main.cpp!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << right <<setw( 30 ) << "\nAIRPORT MANAGER" << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Any help will be appreciate :)

Comment: You have a comma after your arguments, but no argument identifier, why?

Comment: Also why do you use C++ methods, such as std::string, but use a C method to copy it?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94b729466945658d) other than the potential double include of `"date.h"` if that file doesn't have a proper include guard. Also, `using namespace std;` in header files is a terrible idea.

Comment: @T.C. using namespace std anywhere in your code is a terrible idea imho. using namespace <anything> is also a bad idea imo.

Comment: You need a semicolon after `set( n, ln, ncode, d, m, y )`  (and probably change `d,m,y` to `D`).

Comment: @user3728501: It's not exactly "terrible" when used in the scope of a very small function. Perhaps not really needed, but there are far worse things.

Comment: @ChristianHackl The one to watch out for is usually `double var = abs(other_var)` and `double var = std::abs(other_var)` - One gives you extra free truncation.

Comment: @user3728501 1.which argument do you mean? may you edit one?

Comment: @ChristianHackl I had read about Not to use namespace std but i considered its not for a small piece of code! although i didnt understand your example! looks ur right! I need date.h in aircrew too and omiting date.h couses lots of errors!

Comment: @n.m. i changed it as you said! also semicolon was omited while coping here, still i have the problem

Comment: @EAGER: I don't know what "example" you mean, but yes, `using namespace` should only be used in "small pieces of code" aka "in small scopes".

Comment: If you want exact and complete answers, post exact and compete code you have. Copy and paste entire source files, all of them. date.h is missing.

Comment: @EAGER All your arguments in Person, Aircrew and Set. (Inside header files.) I was curious as to why you omitted the identifiers which you were to use in the implementation.

Comment: @n.m. here you are!(post is edited) any thing else? :)

Comment: Posted code does not trigger the errors you say it triggers. [Demo](http://ideone.com/lW348f). It's all of your code as is minus custom `#include`s. The only thing I have added is `#include <cstring>` (necessary for str... functions). Voting to close as non-reproducible.

Comment: @ChristianHackl i mean what you said above:to watch out 'double var = abs(other_var)' and 'double var = std::abs(other_var)'

Comment: @n.m. i tried the code in C::B as you done  and the result was the same, but its just a bag of codes! is there any way to run it in standard files? i made another project and just added these files you see above (without left files of the project) nothing changed!

Comment: Your classes have no include guards, you should add them. Other than that, I have no idea.

Comment: @user3728501  i tried to have a code style like the colleges reference _Cpp How to Program 8th Edition 2011 program_ by _Deitel & Deitel_ as i know there is no identifier in header files, also i agree that its better to mention them to make the code more readable.And may you tell me the way that strings are converted to char array in c++ ? now i have to include both <string> and <cstring> ! tnx anyway :)

Comment: @n.m. have added them, I'm grateful, you helped a lot :)